# Django-allauth setup

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-socialauth, django-allauth

I just completed install django-allauth and I'm receiving the following message when I navigate to the template page for all social providers:

```
AttributeError at /account/facebook/login/
'tuple' object has no attribute 'get'
```

settings.social_account_providers

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = ( 
{'facebook':
  {'SCOPE': ['email', 'publish_stream'], 
   'FB_LOGIN': {'auth_type': 'reauthenticate'},
   'METHOD': 'js_sdk'}},
{ 'twitter':
    { 'SCOPE': ['r_emailaddress'] } },
{ 'google':
    { 'SCOPE': ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile']}},
{ 'linkedin':
    { 'SCOPE': ['r_emailaddress'] }}
```

)

html

```
<a method="js_sdk" href="{% provider_login_url "Facebook" %}"></a>
```

Comment: I think there's some code missing here. Somewhere the API is returning a tuple which you try to access like you do on a dict using `.get()`. A tuple is accessed by index like this `myTuple[0]` for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS` setting should be a dictionary (`{...}`). I suspect that in your case it is a tuple -- I see you are using tuple brackets.

Try this:

```
python manage.py shell
>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> type(settings.SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS)
<type 'dict'>
```

Does it say `<type 'dict'>` in your case?

Comment: actually, no it says <type 'tuple'>

Comment: That is the problem. It should say dict. Make sure to use `SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = { ... }`  -- as in, drop the tuple brackets.